# How to implement d3 word cloud in Angular 4+?

Tags: d3.js, angular6, angular8, word-cloud, d3-cloud

There is no proper npm package for Angular. We have for angularjs 1.x and react, not for Angular2+. Is there any way to we can implement the [word cloud](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/) in Angular. Any help would be much appreciated.